# How can I pass a char array as the parameter to a function?

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, string, pointer, array

I am creating a menu for adjusting system variables.

The menu is made up of pointers like so:

```
char* options4[] = {"hMin1", "hMax1", "refr1", "fSpeed1"};
```

I want to pass the selected string as the parameter for an 'adjust' function for use in some conditional logic and for display on a HCMAX7219 7 segment display. Here's what I've got:

```
int option = 0;
float variable = 82.0;

if(Serial.available() > 0) {
  key = Serial.read();
  if(key == back) {
    return;
  } else if(key == fwd) {
    float newVar = adjust(String(options4[option%4]), variable);
  } else if(key == down) {
    option++;
  } else if(key == up) {
    option--;
  }
}

float adjust(char* str, float var) {
  ...do some stuff...
  display.print7Seg(str, 8);
  EDIT: forgot this call..
  display.print7Seg(var, 1, 4);
  ...do stuff to var...
  return var;
}
```

The library function takes `(char[] TextString, unsigned int Offset)` as it's parameters.

EDIT: the library also has functions `print7Seg(long number, byte decimalPlace, unsigned int Offset)` and `print7Seg(long number, unsigned int Offset)`

Now I'm new to pointers, but I can see that I am passing a pointer to my adjust function, and expecting it to dig out a char array from memory. I can't see any problems with that, though I may be missing something. When I try to compile, the IDE just crashes with exit status 84; so no debug info.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

There are one or two things missing in your code. Where is setup() and loop()? Or is it just a snippet?

But answer to the question first. This is not right:

```
newVar = adjust(String(options4[option%4]), variable);
```

Should be:

```
newVar = adjust(options4[option%4], variable);
```

You want to index the vector of strings and pass one of the elements to the function.

Cheers!

Comment: It is just a snippet yeah. The full code is about 300 lines so thought I'd try to keep it brief. There are 12 variables to adjust so a generic function is what I'm aiming for.
You're absolutely right about the typecasting on the function call, I didn't spot that. 
I've commented that line out for compilation, as I'm yet to think of a way of assigning the variable, so that's not the cause.
Thanks for the spot though.

Comment: Do you mean the cause of the IDE crash?

Comment: Yeah, the cause of the IDE crash could be linked to a problem in the code.

Comment: Then you will have to post all the code and tell us about the Arduino IDE version, board, etc. Have you turned on the "Show verbose output during:" in the IDE Preferences? Collect as much info as possible before the crash of the IDE.

Comment: And I would also suggest changing the title of this post??

Comment: I think the cause of the crash was an attempt by the library to treat a float as a long. I don't know a whole lot about the compilation process, but changing this seems to have solved the problem.. it compiles at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35476/discussion-between-xeuari-and-mikael-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Ah .. ok I've just figured it out..

This *is* a legitimate way to pass char arrays to functions.

The original `char* options4[]` array is just an array of pointers to char arrays in memory, so passing one of these pointers to a function works fine.

The culprite was actually my float parameter, I was trying to make a library function call with a float to this function: `print7Seg(long number, byte decimalPlace, unsigned int Offset)`.

This is what was causing the IDE to crash.

I got around it by having an int version of each of the variables I need to set. Then typecasting and dividing by a float to get variables that will be used in the main program. like so:

```
int hMin1Int = 820;
float hMin1 = (float)hMin1Int / 10.0;
int hMax1Int = 880;
float hMax1 = (float)hMax1Int / 10.0;
int refr1 = 30; //minutes
int fSpeed1 = 128;
```

I was then able to change my function to accept an `int`, the library function, so far, seems to be ok treating an int as a long, but if not I can just make all my ints longs:

```
int adjust(char* str, int var) {
  ...do some stuff...
  display.print7Seg(str, 8);
  display.print7Seg(var, 1, 4);
  ...do stuff to var...
  return var;
}
```

I was asking the wrong question!

Still I hope this will be useful to someone, so I will leave it up. Thanks for the response Mikael Patel.

Moral of the story, know your library.